# Is there a way to display the same amount of information on the watch face of the Apple Watch but using less complications?

Tags: apple-watch, apple-watch.app, watchos

This is all of the information I like being able to access on my watch several times a day without having to go into the list of apps.

[image]

*French time, shortcut to record an activity, numeric US PT time, activity rings, voice recorder, date, timer shortcut, sunrise/sunset.*

The only way I have found to gather all this information on just one face is by using the “infographics” face. However I do not need the classic watch face with the minute and hour hands, since I already have numeric time which I prefer, but this is the one thing that I cannot remove.

Would there be a way for me to have all of the information available on this watch face by using less complication spots? (For example date and numeric time gathered in one place?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Apple has what you need and you'll want to investigate third party options.

- [Watchsmith](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/watchsmith/id1483088503) by David Smith - https://david-smith.org/about/

The developer of [Watchsmith](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/watchsmith/id1483088503) is one I've respected for a long time and their [Widgetsmith](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/widgetsmith/id1523682319) is amazingly powerful. There are many tutorials online and it can be a challenge to get an iOS app that intends to add watch faces past App review, but you might be able to make just what you want if you're willing to tinker and don't want to hire out that development effort to existing software (there are several other apps in the store already, just I linked to the one I think may be best for you)

- [Complication Lab](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/complication-lab/id1537137580#?platform=iphone) (this also would be excellent if you need new complications)
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10046/
- [DIY a face yourself with Xcode and avoid app review](https://medium.com/@yuyouwu5/tutorial-creating-a-custom-apple-watch-face-and-get-rejected-by-the-app-store-6e7f7f1959de)
- https://github.com/YuyouWu/WatchFace/tree/master

Looking over the list of faces, Modular devotes less space to the time and more to the complications, but only has 6 whereas yours has 8.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/faces-and-features-apde9218b440/watchos